# logrotate does not rotate at the time specified in crontab

Tags: cron, logrotate

I am wondering why logrotate does not rotate my logfiles at the time which it is called through crontab.

My entry in crontab is:

> 50 2 * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate

Therefore all my logs should be rotated at night at 2:50 am. I receive a status mail from my server that logrotate is called at 2:50, so this seems to be working.

The logs are rotated correctly - but not at 2:50, they are rotated at 9:30 am.

I googled for more the 2h, checked logrotate.conf, my files at logrotate.d, but I can´t find any configuration that could cause that time delay. I would be grateful for a hint about what could cause this behavior and how I can modify it (the settings were configured by my predecessor and I he left me no documentation)

Comment: I think the question is offtopic here because it is not related to programming. The superuser is a better place for such kind of questions.

Comment: I think you are right -> I moved the question to superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/1238419/logrotate-does-not-rotate-at-the-time-specified-in-crontab